# Why do SQL FullText queries slow down when you OR?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

In SQL Server (2008), I have a FullText index on two columns, call them `Table1.FirstNames` and `Table2.LastNames`.  After profiling some queries, I came up with the following results:

```
SELECT *
FROM (Table1 LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.SomeKey=Table2.SomeKey)
WHERE CONTAINS(FirstNames, 'Bob') OR CONTAINS(LastNames, 'Bob')
```

=> 31 197ms

```
SELECT *
FROM (Table1 LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.SomeKey=Table2.SomeKey)
WHERE (FirstNames LIKE '%Bob%') OR CONTAINS(LastNames, 'Bob')
```

=> 1941ms

```
SELECT *
FROM (Table1 LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.SomeKey=Table2.SomeKey)
WHERE CONTAINS(FirstNames, 'Bob') OR LastNames LIKE '%Bob%'
```

=> 3201ms

```
SELECT *
FROM (Table1 LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.SomeKey=Table2.SomeKey)
WHERE CONTAINS(FirstNames, 'Bob')
```

=> 565ms

```
SELECT *
FROM (Table1 LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.SomeKey=Table2.SomeKey)
WHERE FirstNames LIKE '%Bob%'
```

=> 670ms

```
SELECT *
FROM (Table1 LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.SomeKey=Table2.SomeKey)
WHERE CONTAINS(LastNames, 'Bob')
```

=> 17ms

```
SELECT *
FROM (Table1 LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.SomeKey=Table2.SomeKey)
WHERE LastNames LIKE '%Bob%'
```

=> 3ms

This behaviour persists even if I rebuild the FullText index.

FullText is usually much faster than a LIKE query over large sets of data in a specific language, but why do query speeds slow down by an order of magnitude when I OR together two FullText clasues?

Comment: How well does `WHERE FirstNames Like '%Bob%' OR LastNames Like '%Bob%'` work?

Comment: About 2 seconds (I'm working with him on this)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does changing to using `ContainsTable` help?

It did here [Adding more OR searches with CONTAINS Brings Query to Crawl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906812/adding-more-or-searches-with-contains-brings-query-to-crawl/2907331#2907331)

And the same answerer ([Joe Stefanelli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/341251/joe-stefanelli)) managed to bring about a similar improvement by changing `FREETEXT` predicates combined with `OR` to a `FREETEXTTABLE`  here [SQL Server full text query across multiple tables - why so slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061151/sql-server-full-text-query-across-multiple-tables-why-so-slow/3062096#306209)

Comment: Do I get the reputation points if this answer is accepted? :-)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should read this: [SQL Server 2005 Full-Text Queries on Large Catalogs: Lessons Learned](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917695.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I'd take a look at the execution plan for each of those.  I'm guessing you will learn quite a bit from that.

[Here is a decent link](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/tips/query_execution_plan_analysis_p1.aspx) that will show you how to display the execution plan as well as some tips on interpreting it.